# Optimize I/O to a large file in C

Tags: c, optimization, io

I have written a C program that reads data from a huge file(>3 GB). Each record in the file is a key-value pair. Whenever a query comes, the program searches for the key and retrieves the corresponding value, similarly for updating the value.
The queries are coming at a fast rate so this technique will eventually fail.
The worst case access time is too large. Creating an in-memory object will again be a bad idea, because of the size.
Is there any way in which this problem can be sorted out?

Comment: If you aren't creating new keys much: sort the whole thing based on key to allow binary searching (and maybe even divide in to multiple files based on this sorted order).

Comment: Can you convert the file into a proper database?

Comment: This seems like the ideal case for some [NoSQL databases](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL#Key-value_store), you may want to have a look at them.

Comment: access/update time in database vs. file? @Glenn : Yes i can convert, but the problem is again the access time.

Comment: What OS? 32bit or 64bit? in Linux RAM backed to swap, is the same as RAM (cache) backed to a file, for performance. Also both can be memory mapped, both can be accessed via read/write/seek calls, but for a 32bit application you wont be able to memory map all that at same time. Memory mapped should be more performent as will have less system calls. Unless you know what you are doing, and are writing a database, then use an existing database.

Answer (score 5):

Sure seems to me a file of that size wrapping a series of name-value pairs is begging to be migrated to an actual database; failing that, I'd probably at least explore the idea of a memory-mapped file, with only portions resident at any given time...

Answer (score 3):

How large are the keys, in comparison to their corresponding values?  If they are significantly smaller, you might try creating a table in memory between the keys and the corresponding locations within the file of their values.